# Webpack only bundling a single Typescript file instead of all dependencies

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I'm trying to bundle my Typescript project files including all dependencies from node_modules into a single file but I'm having trouble with Webpack. I've tried lots of options but whatever I do it just seems to include the entry file *only* in the output:

Some sample Typescript files that have a dependency:

app/test1.ts:

```
import {x} from 'app/test2';

let y = x + 1;
```

app/test2.ts:

```
export let x = 123;
```

The Webpack file:

```
module.exports = {
entry: {
 'app/startup' : './app/test1'
},
output: {
  filename: 'bundle.js'
},
module: {
  loaders: [
    { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }
  ]
},
resolve: {
  modules: [
    'node_modules'
  ],
  extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
},
};
```

The tsconfig.json file:

```
 {
  "atom": {
      "rewriteTsconfig": false
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "pretty": false,
      "allowJs": false,
      "outDir": "tsDist",
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "target": "es5",
      "module": "es2015",
      "sourceMap": false,
      "strictNullChecks": true,
      "noImplicitThis": true,
      "noImplicitAny": false,
      "declaration": false
  },
  "filesGlob": [
      "app/**/*.ts",
  ],
  "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
  ],
  "files": [
  ]
 }
```

Besides the standard stuff that goes at the top of the bundle, it only contains this with "app/test2" missing:

```
System.register(["app/test2"], function (exports_1, context_1) {
    "use strict";
    var __moduleName = context_1 && context_1.id;
    var test2_1, y;
    return {
        setters: [
            function (test2_1_1) {
                test2_1 = test2_1_1;
            }
        ],
        execute: function () {
            y = test2_1.x + 1;
        }
    };
});
```

What am I doing wrong here? Why is test2 not being included in the bundle? What would I need to do to include any node_module dependencies as well?

I tried copying the settings from this sample project but just got the same results:
https://github.com/blacksonic/typescript-webpack-tree-shaking

Comment: could you please include your project file structure as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could it be because you refer to the wrong links ?

```
import {x} from './test2'; // you enter 'app/test2'
let y = x + 1;
```